# Is there a way to limit the result AFTER the grouping has taken place?

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit

I am trying to group a steam of posts by hour, so only 1 post shows per hour but I think what is happening is that mysql limits the results then groups them and that leads to posts to appear under an hour.

Is there a way to apply the limit after the grouping as taking place?

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
GROUP BY posts.userid, FLOOR((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(posts .time))/3600) #Hourly limiter
LIMIT 20
```

I want this query to do the grouping before the limiting so I can get accurate results.

Comment: Could you post a sample query? I can't figure out if you mean `LIMIT` or `WHERE`/`HAVING`

Comment: I posted a sample in the question as an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally a HAVING clause is used to filter groups, as the HAVING clause is evaluated on the results of the GROUP BY. See http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-group-by-having/ for examples.

Comment: To be precise: HAVING filters the aggregate (MAX, SUM etc). The group (GROUP BY) can be filtered in the WHERE